# For every new client tomcat is not creating new session id rather getSession() method giving old session id used by some other client

Tags: java

Whenever client opens new web browser that client is treated as new client by the **tomcat container** and **getSession(true)** returns new session id for the client.

If client opens *5 web browser* then *5 unique session id* is created by the container but in my case **getSession(true)** method returns old session id for every new client.

For example if i call `getSession()` method for client one then container generate `B0B7945E63D00701E19FA6E9A4909B07` session id for client one, when second client come, i again call `getSession()` method but this time `getSession()` method return old session id which is generated for client one.

So, the data which i set in session id for client one is reflected to client two also and if 5 or more client come then `getSession()` is returning old session id which is generated for client one to all clients.

Comment: Did you use different browsers? open 1 IE, 1 Firefox and 1 Chrome see if all get the same? In practice they will get different IDs. But if you open IE again you will get the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration is to have the session id exchanged in a cookie between the server and the browser. Because HTTP is inherently a non connected protocol, and sessions is just an ugly(*) hack to simulate connexions.

If one single client (machine) open 5 browser applications or windows **of same browser**, all will share the same cookie bag ... and will also share same session ! I've been told that some recent browsers actuallys try to cope with that, but I've never tested it.

When I have to test different sessions from one single machine, I use firefox, IE and Chrome to have different cookie bags.

(*) *ugly* is just my opinion, but the fact is that a server cannot reliably know if the client has closed the browser, and you have to use sophisticated patterns to avoid session hijacking (ok security framework can do it for you, *provided you ask them to*)

Answer (score 0):

According to specification:

> getSession (boolean create) **returns the current HttpSession
>   associated with this request** or, if there is no current session
>   and create is true, returns a new session.

For me it seems, that every user operates within the same instance of `HttpServletRequest`, that is why `getSession(true)` always returns the same object. It is a long shot, but do you call `new HttpServletRequest` when a new user tries to connect to your service?